# Greasemonkey: "GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined" with the new update

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

Why this simple Greasemonkey script is not working for me https://jsfiddle.net/pghnsw8z/1/ ? I mean that instead of getting successful response I get error while making an ajax call.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Starter AJAX request in GM, TM, etc.
// @match       *://php.net/*
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @connect     php.net
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     'GET',
    url:        'http://php.net/',
    onload:     function (responseDetails) {
                    // DO ALL RESPONSE PROCESSING HERE...
                                alert(responseDetails);
                    console.log (
                        "GM_xmlhttpRequest() response is:\n",
                        responseDetails.responseText.substring (0, 80) + '...'
                    );
                }
} );
```

I found the script here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592356/9483949 and it seems it worked well for someone earlier.

I'm using Firefox 59.0.1 and Greasemonkey 4.3

Restarting Firefox and reinstalling script didn't help.

Comment: GM4 has abandoned the classic API, see their documentation, now it's GM.*

Comment: @wOxxOm In this case I get `GM.xmlhttpRequest is not a function`

Comment: The new API function uses uppercase H.

Comment: @wOxxOm Perfect! thank's a lot.

Comment: Peter, as per GM's own recommendation, you should switch to Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.  The new Greasemonkey is severely degraded, not backwards compatible, and has significantly less utility than the other engines.

Comment: @Brock Adams Thank's for pointing that out for me.

Comment: use GM.* in new scripts, add [polyfill](https://github.com/greasemonkey/gm4-polyfill) to old scripts. One line, too easy. A suggestion for users (just users) if a script was not updated by one of these methods is that [they might to switch to tampermonkey meanwhile](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html). GM is not dying. Why is not GM adding the polyfill automatically? Maybe wanted to force the change.

Answer (score 4):

The doc : https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.xmlHttpRequest

The GM API was changed. You have to use xmlHttpRequest property of GM class, it is compatibility: GM 4.0+.

Replace `GM_xmlhttpRequest` by : `GM.xmlHttpRequest` like this :

```
// ==UserScript==
// ...
// @grant         GM.xmlHttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

GM.xmlHttpRequest({
```